# Can`t compile with moderncv package

Tags: moderncv

Currently I cannot compile using the `moderncv` package. I just get the message

> File moderncv-additions.sty not found

I am using MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit. When I used it the last time in september I did not have any problems. And I did not change anything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you installed the whole package? Try updating your distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The current `moderncv` package is version 2.0.0 and is integrated in **complete** current MiKTeX 2.9.

The file `moderncv-additions.sty` is not part of official `moderncv`, it is an addition for a special version, collected in file `bewerbungsmappe.zip`, based on version 0.8 from 2010/05/24.

With updateing MiKTeX to the current version and with already installed class `moderncv` you also update `moderncv` to curreent version 2.0.0.  Then there is no file `moderncv-additions.sty` available.

If you insist in running this outdated version you can download the [file `bewerbungsmappe.zip`](https://latex.tugraz.at/vorlagen/diverse) from TU Graz, extract all files into a new directory and add there your own CV TeX code.

Comment: Any suggestions to update the files which worked in the past with moderncv-additions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not part of MiKTeX, nor does it  seem to be an official package. You can find a file of this name [here](https://github.com/mgruebler/ShirleyTemplate/blob/master/Bsp/templates/bewerbungsmappe/moderncv-additions.sty) on GitHub.